# When doing addAll on other arraylist, both arraylists references same elements

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

When I add all the contents of an `ArrayList` to another `ArrayList`, the other `ArrayList` contains references to elements of the first `ArrayList`. Hence, when I change an element in either of the `List`s, the corresponding element in the other `List` also changes. This clearly means `addAll` assigns references to the new `List`.

Reference code:

```
ArrayList<StringBuffer> a = new ArrayList<>();
a.add(new StringBuffer("1"));
a.add(new StringBuffer("2"));
a.add(new StringBuffer("3"));

ArrayList<StringBuffer> b = new ArrayList<>();
b.addAll(a);

System.out.println("Arralists" + " before: ");
System.out.println("A arraylist" + a.toString());
System.out.println("B arraylist" + b.toString() + "\n\n");

a.set(0, a.get(0).replace(0, 1, String.valueOf(4)));

System.out.println("Arralists after " + "updating a: ");
System.out.println("A arraylist" + a.toString());
System.out.println("B arraylist" + b.toString() + "\n\n");
```

Corresponding logs:

```
Arralists before: 
A arraylist[1, 2, 3]
B arraylist[1, 2, 3]


Arralists after updating a: 
A arraylist[4, 2, 3]
B arraylist[4, 2, 3]
```

I want to know the best way to avoid references and create a copy array.

**EDIT**

I want to do this in android. @Eran suggested an answer with Java8 but compatibility issues come up with that. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I know that, I want to avoid this reference thing and hence the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> This clearly means addall assigns references to the new list.

That's correct.

> I want to know the best way to avoid references and create a copy array.

Don't use `addAll`. Iterate over the input `List` and create a copy of each element of that `List`.

For example, using Java 8 `Stream`s and taking advantage of the existing copy constructor `StringBuffer(CharSequence seq)`:

```
List<StringBuffer> b = a.stream().map(StringBuffer::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Without `Stream`s, you can use a `for` loop:

```
List<StringBuffer> b = new ArrayList<>();
for (StringBuffer sb : a) {
    b.add(new StringBuffer(sb));
}
```

Comment: As a side note, use `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`: " [The StringBuilder class should generally be used in preference to this one, as it supports all of the same operations but it is faster, as it performs no synchronization"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html)

Comment: But I want to do this in android, and there emerges the compatibility issues.

Comment: @parekhkruti26 you can do the same with a for loop. No need to use Streams.

Comment: Creating new objects always is a memory heavy operation. And I use arraylists with POJOs. :(

Comment: However, I guess there is no other way out other than this. Thanks for your help :). But I still await some other way if it comes in future or some other way. Hence, +1 on your answer but not accepting it as of now.

Comment: @parekhkruti26 No, there isn't. If you need 2 lists with distinct elements, you must create new objects.